# PrimeFaces data table different rowkey for different p:column

Tags: primefaces

How do I add 2 checkbox columns in data table with different rowkey? 
When I add 2 columns with selectionMode which is 'Delete' and 'Confirm', I face the problem that whenever I check one of the 'Delete' or 'Confim', it select both.
It is Because I used same rowKey in data table.
That why I would like to ask that how can I separate rowKey for each column.

Comment: Not possible... Create your own 'selection mechanism' for that.

Comment: why not use a commandButton to delete and another one to confirm ?!?

Comment: Yes I could use commandButton but the problem is whenever I click one of the checkbox in data table header which for 'Delete' or 'Confirm', it is selected all for both coulumns...although action is going separately...